# Time period of an oscillating drop of liquid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, surface-tension

We have a drop of liquid as shown, which is given a gentle push such that it begins oscillating, without tearing apart. We know surface tension $S$, density $\rho$, and radius $R$.

[image]

I can't figure how to make a conventional SHM differential equation and find out the time period accurately. Instead, I used dimensional analysis to find out the time period partially:

$$[T]=[S]^a[\rho]^b[R]^c$$
$$[T]=[MT^{-2}]^a[ML^{-3}]^b[L]^c$$

So now comparing the quantities and solving equations finally yield us:
$$T=k\sqrt{\frac{\rho R^3}{S}}$$

But the constant $k$ still can't be precisely or at all be found by dimensional analysis. So I need help here, especially how to proceed by making differential equation of SHM, or by some other way. Every help is massively appreciated.

Comment: You've made a slip in your algebra. You need to exchange the $S$ and $\rho$ in your 'final' equation. This will then make more sense: you'd hardly expect increasing the density of the liquid to reduce the periodic time, would you? Going beyond the dimensional approach to a full analysis, even an approximate one, takes you into deep waters. Most undergraduate Physics courses won't fully equip you to undertake it. Consider, perhaps, whether you really need to do it. Or hope for an answer here, of course.

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks for informing me, it was a typo and is now corrected. So you are saying, solving fully is very advanced? I would be able to understand mathematics if it's not very advanced like multivariable calculus, or tensors etc.

Comment: I'd guess that an energy-based approach would be easiest. It's no doubt not difficult to work out how the surface area (and therefore the surface energy) changes with eccentricity for an ellipsoid at constant volume, but I think it would be harder to handle the kinetic energy changes. But then you might know more fluid dynamics than I do. Good luck with your enterprise.

Comment: How do you even know this will exhibit SHM?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I am not sure it would exhibit SHM, but it is oscillating, so maybe it could exhibit SHM, but again, I am not sure.

Comment: I'd be rather surprised if it doesn't exhibit SHM, at least for very small oscillations, but I'm not claiming to know!

Comment: @PhilipWood That would be told by equation of its motion, which I asked help for :)

Comment: Exactly so. Let's hope someone will supply that help.

Comment: This looks to be discussed in Lamb's *Hydrodynamics*, p. 473.  For a quadrupole displacement (as you've drawn it above), his result is (I think) that $k = 2 \pi/\sqrt{8}$.  However, I'm not versed enough in hydrodynamics to be able to post his treatment in a detailed answer.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I would really like someone to explain it in simpler manner. Ig its on pg 461 instead of 473. But it's based heavily on standing waves ig, which I have not advanced knowledge of.